# Как ускорить быстродействие?

Tags: c#, словари, производительность, рефакторинг

я только учусь работе на C#.
У меня есть задача, нужно составьте словарь самых частотных продолжений биграмм и триграмм.
Я написала свое решение, на простых тестах все летает. А вот основной проваливает, нужно, чтобы разделяло книгу на <300 страниц менее чем за 10 секунд.
Уже все перепробовала, даже разделение на многопоточность, уже linq объединение добавила, ничего не помогает.
Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать как можно ускорить?
Вот мой код:

```
namespace TextAnalysis
{
    static class FrequencyAnalysisTask
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetMostFrequentNextWords(List<List<string>> text)
        {
            var nGramm = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
            nGramm = GetNGramm(text, nGramm);
            var frequentNgrams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            frequentNgrams = GetFrequentGramm(frequentNgrams, nGramm);
            return frequentNgrams;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> GetNGramm(List<List<string>> text, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> nGramm)
        {
            foreach (var sentences in text)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < (sentences.Count - 1);)
                {
                    if (!nGramm.ContainsKey(sentences[i]))
                        nGramm.Add(sentences[i], new Dictionary<string, int>());

                    if (!nGramm[sentences[i]].ContainsKey(sentences[i + 1]))
                        nGramm[sentences[i]].Add(sentences[i + 1], 1);
                }
            }
            return nGramm;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFrequentGramm(Dictionary<string, string> frequentResult, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> nGramm)
        {
            foreach (var word in nGramm) 
            {
                frequentResult.Add(word.Key, word.Value.OrderByDescending(wordsValue => wordsValue.Value)
                    .ThenBy(wordsKey => wordsKey.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal).First().Key); 
            }

            return frequentResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<List<string>> text` - сделайте `string[][] text`, станет немного быстрее.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < (sentences.Count - 1);)` выглядит как бесконечный цикл, так как i нигде не увеличивается. Проверьте правильность вставленного кода. Возможно оно и тест проваливает, потому что зацикливается навечно.

Comment: `составьте словарь самых частотных продолжений биграмм и триграмм` я не понял, можно про это поподробней? И как выглядят данные на входе и выходе, можно примеры?

Comment: @tym32167  вот ссылка на задачу https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming/eb894d4d-5854-4684-898b-5480895685e5

Answer (score -1):

Во первых, как было подмечанно из комментариев у вас имеется бесконечный цикл

```
for (var i = 0; i < (sentences.Count - 1);)
{
    if (!nGramm.ContainsKey(sentences[i]))
        nGramm.Add(sentences[i], new Dictionary<string, int>());

    if (!nGramm[sentences[i]].ContainsKey(sentences[i + 1]))
        nGramm[sentences[i]].Add(sentences[i + 1], 1);
}
```

i нигде не меняется.
Так же данная запись не считается лаконичной и достаточно правильной.

```
List<List<string>>
```

Рекомендую перейти к следующей записи

```
string[][] text
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "не считается лаконичной и достаточно правильной." ?

Comment: Лаконичность (лаконизм) , краткость, сжатость, немногословность — изложение мыслей с использованием наименьшего количества слов. Говорят, что краткость — сестра таланта. Для того, чтобы излагать кратко, необходимо отделять главное от второстепенного, концентрировать изложение на контексте, убирать из текста нагромождение лишних слов. Краткость ценится как в письменном и устном языке, так и в языках программирования.
Лаконично - кратко, сжато.